# How can I load a pdf file to html page?

Tags: html, pdf, embed

following is the part of my code in which I'm trying to load the pdf file:

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <embed width="600" height="450" src="/pathOnMyPcFromROOT/myfile.pdf"
         type="application/pdf"
    </embed>
</div>
```

I only get [this(Click Here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whhBe.png)........
is there a way to fix it? is there a way to click on a  link and the pdf loads in a new tab?

Comment: I'm not an expert in html but is the src path correct? Should it start with / which would suggest upper most folder. Perhaps it should be pathOnMyPcFromRoot/myfile.pdf or maybe you want it from the root.

Comment: Oh I forgot... Is the path for the source file accessible with your http process.

Comment: @AdmiralNoiseBottom I'm using the same path for the same directory but for a different file. it's an xml file that I'm loading to the parser and it is working. So, I assume the directory is accessible by the http process?

Comment: @AdmiralNoiseBottom Ok I found the problem: when I used the xml loader I had to put the path all the way from the root for it to work. Apparently that is not the case for accessing the pdf file. I only had to start the path from the directory where my php file resides. Thank you for ur help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try an iframe tag:

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <iframe src="files/myfile.pdf" width="600" height="450">
</div>
```

Note that the webserver software (xampp? mamp? lamp?) should not allow you to access the PDF file except with reference to webroot. The best idea is to put it into a folder inside your folder that contains the index.php (or index.html) file:

```
public_html (a.k.a. htdocs or www)
    - css (folder)
    - files (folder)
        - myfile.pdf
    - js (folder)
    - img (folder)
    - index.html (file)
```

Comment: Ok I found the problem: when I used the xml loader I had to put the path all the way from the root for it to work. Apparently that is not the case for accessing the pdf file. I only had to start the path from the directory where my php file resides. You were right. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

mess around with this. I use it all the time. Change the css padding to suit your needs and also change the html width and height. This is a responsive code, so it adapts to all screen sizes

```css
/* Flexible iFrame */
 
.flexible-container {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    padding-top: 30px;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
 
.flexible-container iframe,   
.flexible-container object,  
.flexible-container embed {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!-- Responsive iFrame -->
<div class="flexible-container">
<iframe src=source here" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
</div>
```